# How to match nested italic font tags with Xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Consider an `xml` structure like the following

```
<p class="long">
  <i>Malicious</i>
  " is the adjective based on the noun "
  <i>malice</i>
  ", which means the desire to harm others. Both words come from the latin word "
</p>
```

I want to select all text inside the `<p>` tag.
I tried with

```
examples = tree.xpath('//p[@class="long"]/text()')
```

With this, however, all text between `<i>` tags is ignored for some reason.

What is the correct way to extract all the text inside the `<p>` tags, regardless of it being also contained in other nested tags?

Comment: Here is my result:  [' is the adjective based on the noun ', ', which means the desire to harm others. Both words come from the Latin word ', ", for bad. If someone is malicious he doesn't jus
t make bad things happen; he loves to make bad things happen."]

Comment: Please make questions self-contained, rather than depending on links to an external site. SO aims to create a searchable archive of questions and answers, and links to external sites compromise that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
examples=tree.xpath('//p[@class="long"]//text()')
```

(with the double slash before `text()`, which also matches nodes that aren't direct children)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the use of text() unless you have very special requirements - for exactly this reason. You're probably interested in the string value of the `p` element, not in its child text and element nodes. Exactly how to select this depends on the environment (does your XPath API allow returning a string rather than a node-set? Does it support XPath 2.0? Does your path expression select more than one "p" element? Can you just return the `p` element, and then get its string value in the host application?)